# Prefill input text box from confirmation box

Tags: javascript, input, textbox, confirm, autofill

Does anyone know a way i can achieve the following?

When a user enters 1 into the input box an alert popups but then i want the user to be able to either confirm the new value and it auto fills the input field with the minimum value or cancel and the field remains blank.

i have the following code so far:

```
function Form_Validator(theForm)
{
    var err = false;
    var field;
    var msg = 'Please correct the following to continue...\n';
    var alpha = /\w/;
    var numeric = /[^0-9^\s]/;
    var emailvalidator = /\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/;

    var teststr = '';


        if(theForm.prod_quantity.value == '1'){
        msg += '\nThe minimum order amount is 2.';
        if (!err){
            field = theForm.prod_quantity;
            err = true;
        }
    }

        if (!err){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        alert(msg);
        field.focus();
        return false;
    }
}


<b>Quantity:</b> <input type="text" class="prod_quantity" name="prod_quantity"  />
<input type="submit" value="" class="add-basket-btn"/>
```

i have managed to make an alert box appear however i am not sure how to make it autofill in so that the value becomes 2 if they click ok. i hope this makes sense.

Comment: You can use `var p = prompt('Input a value');` which gives `p` equals entered String or `null`, or you can use `var c = confirm('Press Okay');` which gives `c` equal to `true` on Okay press or `false` on cancel press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple `confirm()` dialog instead of `alert()` in a condition and set the desired value in your input box:

```
if (confirm (msg)) {  // ask for confirmation
   // set the new value 
   theForm.prod_quantity.value = 2;
} else {
   // leave the box blank
   theForm.prod_quantity.value = '';
}
​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
var orderAmount = confirm(msg);
if ( orderAmount ) theForm.prod_quantity.value = "2";
```